# UIScrollView being clipped when added in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a subclass of UIScrollView and I am trying to add it to my view. For some reason when I add it in the viewDidLoad it works as expected. But when I try adding it in the viewWillAppear then it seems to change the contentSize (although when I print the contentSize it is 905 in either case)

This works as expected:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    diptic = [[DipticView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    diptic.item = self.item;
    [self.view addSubview:diptic];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

[image]

This cuts off the scrollView (both views are scrolled down all the way.)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    diptic = [[DipticView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    diptic.item = self.item;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view addSubview:diptic];
}
```

[image]

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

EDIT:
 I think the frame is being reset somewhere because if I do :

```
diptic = [[DipticView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
```

I get the same results...

Comment: I don't see any autoresizing mask or auto layout constraints, did you forget to copy them to the question ?

Comment: I am not using auto layout. The diptic get's loaded from a xib file. But is there something else that I need to include?

Comment: It's better to run `addSubview:` method in `viewDidLoad` as that only runs once, while `viewWillAppear` can run multiple times during app's runtime. Not that it explains the bug, but I would say it's not the best practice to put that kind of command in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem but it still doesn't answer the question. I add the subview in viewDidLoad and then change the frame in viewWillAppear. But I still don't get why I would be getting different results.

Comment: I think you might have compensated one mistake with another. The reason to think so is the line `initWithFrame:self.view.frame`, normally you use the `bounds` of the parent view as the `frame` gives you the rect at the parents parent coordinate system. And on top of that we have different options of opaque/translucent top and bottom bars as well as various possible auto-layout settings.